# Sending email JAVAMAIL Error

Tags: smtp, jakarta-mail

I have this problem when I try send a mail from my backend: I process a bean and when I connect with SMTP occurs this problem. Any solution for this? I believe this problem is caused by the spam rules of the destination email provider. Any other idea?

```
Error al enviar mail: 082826664245[3ms] | com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 message content rejected
| session=javax.mail.Session@492ecd4b: com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 550 5.7.1 message content rejected
```

Thanks.

Comment: You should ask the SMTP service provider. There's obviously something in the mail that is being rejected.

Comment: Are you sending something that looks like spam?  Have you tried changing the content of what you're sending?

Comment: Hi Bill, Yeah, this case is intermittent and happen sometimes,  i have the control of the content to send and i think this problem is in the client and not in my backend because the content havent nothing wrong.  thanks..